# How do I search a column for cells that contain certain text, and copy that cell into a new column?

Tags: excel, vba

Im pretty new at VBA code in Excel, and am looking to run a piece that will look for any reference to a string of text in Column A or Column B, and spit out the complete value in Column C.

So, if the word "Test" appears in any cell in Column A or Column B - then paste that value in a list format in Column C.

Its important to note that the search doesnt need to match exactly, it only needs to find the word "Test" - IE: "123Test123" in Column A would still pass and "123Test123" would be written to Column C.

Any help is appreciated on this!

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `Range.Autofilter` or a Find loop.

Comment: Can you edit your post and include the code you have so far? That will show us your skill level and give us a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim AB As Range, r As Range, K As Long
    Set AB = Range("A:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    K = 1
    For Each r In AB
        If InStr(1, r.Value, "Test") > 0 Then
            r.Copy Cells(K, "C")
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Gary's Student. Changed a bit to meet some last minute formatting changes I made, but this works a charm!